# Manage NuGet Packages dialog missing VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I discovered after opening a project I wrote 2 months ago, that the "Manage NuGet Packages" dialog when right-clicking a project is missing after the latest Visual Studio 2017 update version  15.4.4
Is this a bug? Or is MS ditching NuGet?

Regardless, if not a bug or abandonment, how do I get this option back?

I see the Manage Bower Packages as the only option (2 months ago both options were in the drop down).

Comment: Right-click on a Visual C++ project still shows "Manage NuGet packages..." for me running 15.4.4. It's also an option under the Project menu. Can you try creating a new project and seeing if it's there?

Comment: VB.NET and C# projects show no problems. You can try to reset your menus and toolbars looking at this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-customize-menus-and-toolbars-in-visual-studio?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.customize.commands)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: No luck. Tried the reset suggestion and opened a new project (C# web DNCore). Only "Manage Bower Packages" is available.

Comment: It disappeared from all my projects. MVC and webforms. This is definitely a  global setting.

Comment: I went to another PC with the same version installed (15.4.4) and it gave me the  Nuget option, so the problem is my copy of VS is corrupt somewhere - time to reinstall it... again (sigh).

Comment: devenv.exe /ResetSettings
no joy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Manage NuGet Packages dialog missing VS2017

According to some of your own troubleshootings, it seems your Visual Studio/NuGet is corrupt.

So you can try to open the Visual Studio Installer, then navigate to `individual components` tab, find the checkbox `NuGet Package manager`, remove it by uncheck that checkbox. Reinstall this component again.

[image]

If reinstall NuGet Package manager not help you, you can try to repair your Visual Studio or reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: That was going to be my next move, however, I went to the installer and added the DotNet Framework 4.7 SDK & targeting pack (which I was planning to do anyway), and, after completion, found it fixed the problem.
Now Nuget shows up in both the Tools menu and the solution explorer.